# Split array into two arrays by index even or odd in c

Tags: c

How to separate the even position number of an array from the odd position number in C.
Example

```
int arr[]= {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1};
int odd[]= {2,4,6,8,1};
int even[] = {3,5,7,9};
```

Comment: please show some code on which we can comment.

Comment: You can check if number is even by using modulo operator, if you divide a number by 2 like this `n % 2`, you'll get either 0 or 1, if you get 0, the number is even (divisible by two and there's no remainder), otherwise number is odd (not divisible by 2 and you have remainder of 1).

Comment: thank you, but i want to sort this array based on the even-oddness of the position( index), not the number itself.

Comment: I don't see how that makes the difference in what I said, index is a number too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` to get the remainder. If the remainder is nonzero, then the **index** is odd, otherwise even. But index starts from 0 and not 1, thus the first element's index is 0 and is even. if you want to sort according to that (seems to be you do), add 1 to index.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1};  // our array

  const size_t max_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  int odd[max_size];
  size_t odd_cnt = 0;
  int even[max_size];
  size_t even_cnt = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i != max_size; ++i) {
    if ((i + 1) % 2) {  // if (i + 1) % 2 is nonzero, i + 1 is odd
      odd[odd_cnt++] = arr[i];
    } else {
      even[even_cnt++] = arr[i];
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i != odd_cnt; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", odd[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (size_t i = 0; i != even_cnt; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", even[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```